# Selecting items from sharepoint list based on IDs using rest

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I'm tring to get a list of items from sharepoint 2010 list  with specific IDs . 
I'm using the following query Query in javascript
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Absences?$select=AbsenceDate,AbsenceTime&$filter=indexof(Id,'67|68|') ne -1

I just want to get bacjk rows 67 and 68.

I get an error back  saying 
No applicable function found for 'indexof' at position 0 with the specified arguments. The functions considered are: indexof(System.String, System.String).

any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2011-8-Using_SharePoint_REST_API_%24filter_to_specify_multiple_columns.aspx) is excellent regarding how to use filters:

Basically you want to perform an OR-Query, like this:
 /_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Absences?$select=AbsenceDate,AbsenceTime&$filter=(Id%20eq%20'67')%20OR%20(Id%20eq%20'68')